# How to find component in list of strings, note which index of the list it came from

Tags: python, list, search

I need to create a list that has a component along with what board it came from. I have list that contains all components on every board and a list of strings that contains all components on that board.

```py
board = ['C500 C501 C502 L101 ','R100 R101 C500']

comps = ['C500','C501','C502','L101','R100','R101','C500']

combinedlist=[]
for i in range(0,(len(comps))):
    found = False
    for j in range(len(board)):
        if str(comps[i]) in str(board[j]): 
            found = True
            combinedlist.append(comps[i] + ',' + ('Board'+str(int(j+1))))
            break
    if not found:
        combinedlist.append(comps[i] + ', ' + 'NOT FOUND' )
```

I expect the output to be

```
C500 , Board1
C501 , Board1
C502 , Board1
L101 , Board1
R100 , Board2
R101 , Board2
C500 , Board2
```

However when `C500` comes up again it will say `Board1` again.

```
C500 , Board1
C501 , Board1
C502 , Board1
L101 , Board1
R100 , Board2
R101 , Board2
C500 , Board1 # here
```

Comment: how do you know which comps are on board 1 and which one are on board 2 ?

Comment: The board list is split up so that index 0 of the list is a string that has all components on the first board, index 1 has all components on the 2nd board.

Comment: `board = ['C500 ' 'C501 ' 'C502 ' 'L101 ', 'R100 ' 'R101 ' 'C500 ']` -- which of those are on board #1, board #2 or board #3 ?

Comment: C500 , C501 , C502 and L101 are board one they rest are board 2.

Comment: Because you can't distinguish between the first 'C500' and the second, I would suggest you make a dict with the comps as keys and a list as values containing the board names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
board = ['C500 C501 C502 L101 ','R100 R101 C500']
for i, c in enumerate(board) :
    for part in c.strip().split() :
        print part, ', Board%d' % (i+1)
```

output:

```
C500 , Board1
C501 , Board1
C502 , Board1
L101 , Board1
R100 , Board2
R101 , Board2
C500 , Board2
```